# sql only storing 1 request per user, ignores other ones

Tags: php, sql, ticket-system

somehow my mysql database is only storing requests once per user.

I'm planning to create a ticket system for my website, I've created the tables and created a form and a php class see below.

In the case that i would want to create 2 different tickets behind each other it would only store the first ticket but not the second one.

[Screenshot of the submitted form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abM6c.png)

Sql code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Comments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `comment` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `comment_creation_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Conversation` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ticket_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `comment_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `conversation_creation_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ticket_id` (`ticket_id`,`comment_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Tickets` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_question` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `ticket_subject` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_creation_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ticket_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;
```

Php class:

```
<?php
    class ticket_create extends database {

        // Ticket class constructor storing the class variables 
        function __construct($username, $email, $ticket_id, $ticket_subject, $ticket_question){
            $this->username = $username;
            $this->email = $email;
            $this->ticket_id = $ticket_id;
            $this->ticket_subject = $ticket_subject;
            $this->ticket_question = $ticket_question;
        }

        // Function to add the ticket to the database
        function create_ticket(){
            $this->connect();
            $this->execute_query("INSERT INTO Tickets (username, email, ticket_id, ticket_subject, ticket_question) VALUES ('" . $this->username . "', '" . $this->email . "', '" . $this->ticket_id . "', '" . $this->ticket_subject . "', '" . $this->ticket_question . "')");
        }

        // Function to handle the class and execute their functions
        function class_handler(){
            $this->create_ticket();
            return 'The ticket: ' . $this->ticket_id . ' was successfull created.';
        }
    }
?>
```

Call to the php class:

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_POST)){
        require_once('../handling/ticket_create.php');

        $ticket_question = $_POST['ticket_question'];
        $create_ticket = new ticket_create($user->username, $user->email, md5(uniqid($user->username, true)), $ticket_question);
        $ticket_response = $create_ticket->class_handler();
        echo $ticket_response;
    }
?>
```

How would i get it working, that every ticket would be stored?

Comment: *"somehow my mysql database is only storing requests once per user."* - Probably because in the ticket table you have a `UNIQUE KEY` on `username`. If you want more than one ticket per user, remove this constraint.

Comment: Also, can a comment really belong to more than one ticket? You would typically only use a junction table if it could (i.e. many to many relation), otherwise if a comment can only appear on one ticket, you could just add a foreign key `ticket _id` to `conversation` (and any other required fields) and remove the need for a junction table.

Comment: I'm not really that good in sql, and no a comment should only belong to one ticket. ill give it a try, thank you guys! :D

Comment: I would also be inclined to make `id` the primary key of your ticket table instead of the varchar(30) field `ticket_id`. MySQL can only cluster around the primary key, so clustering on a varchar(30) field is not only likely to cause fragmentation, it also makes your other indexes wider (because this field must be stored against all indexes). You can still have a unique `ticket_id`, but this would be better as a UNIQUE KEY with id as the PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: So i could actually remove the conversation table and add a foreign key ticket _id to conversation ? And i could connect them together?

Comment: Exactly. I personally would do something like this - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/60c7c7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
```

username is unique, meaning if you save `banana` once as the username, you can't save `banana` again. Ever.

Remove the unique key from username in your table and it'll all work.

```
ALTER TABLE Tickets DROP INDEX username;
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Tickets` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_question` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `ticket_subject` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_creation_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ticket_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;
```